# Move object same direction as finger swipe on screen in Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, automatic-ref-counting, direction

I want to write a script in c# for a 2d object, in which I need to move object direction and speed as finger swipe on screen. I achieved to move object's speed as finger's speed swipe on screen, but now I want to move object direction (specifically Arc position like in paper through game paper move on same direction as finger swipe). I already searched on google but couldn't find help. Kindly share with me tutorial or any link or code any one who done this earlier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can find the direction by: saving a touch position in a variable(startVector) in 'Touch.Began' phase and then do the same in 'Touch.Ended' phase and save it in a different variable(EndVector). Now you have two vectors (StartVector, EndVector). Now, you can find the direction by: comparing the StartVector 'Y' or 'X' with EndVector 'Y' or 'X'
e.g

```
if(startVector.y > EndVector.y){
//moved left
}else{
//moved right
}
```

Comment: What if, if any arc direction get on swipe?

Comment: if you want to get arc then you have to save array of vectors in 'Touch.Move' phase and record all the position where finger moved then move your object using values you stored in a array

Comment: use third-party plugins :)